# Query for creating join in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two tables A(:id, :random) and B(:id, :flag). I need to do an inner join of A with B on :id and output only those records whose B.flag is true. I wrote a query like this :

```
A.joins(b).where(:flag => 'true')
```

But this translates to A.flag whereas I need B.flag

What should be the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly point specific table:

```
A.joins(b).where(b_table_name: { flag: true })
```